# Display PDF in html from nodejs server

Tags: node.js, pdf

I have a pdf file stored on my node.js/express server and I want to display it in my html page.

In my controller I have the following code : **CONTROLLER**

```
let filePath = process.env.uploads_dir+'/todolists/'+req.params.clid+'/'+req.params.siid+'/'+req.params.fileName;
res.download(filePath);
```

Then, in my html (pug) page I just have this code : (src contains the route that calls the controller) : **PUG**

```
block prepend body
body#page-top.fixed-nav.sticky-footer.bg-dark
    .content-wrapper
        .container-fluid
            embed(width="400", height="400", src="/download/clientName/filename.pdf", type="application/pdf")
```

The pdf viewer shows me an error "Failed to load PDF file". I have already try to use PDFObject and PDF.js but still the same problem and I have also read some questions but nothing too.
*QUESTIONS* :

- [How to send a pdf file from Node/Express app to the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105846/how-to-send-a-pdf-file-from-node-express-app-to-the-browser)

  - [Failed to load pdf document, NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164235/failed-to-load-pdf-document-nodejs)